# Trying to get onClick to work properly on mobile

Tags: reactjs, click, tap

I am implementing a game board where in each grid there is a functionality to toggle and also toggle background image. The problem is it is working with in the desktop properly with mouse. But with a phone the tap is not working properly. I have to tap to select the grid and then tap again to unselect but that does not change the background to normal. But if I tap on another grid the previous grid background changes to normal as it was expected. My code is below.

```
function Grid(): JSX.Element {
    const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [beingHovered, setBeingHovered] = useState(false);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
    const hoverStyle = {
        backgroundImage: "url(/assets/stamp.png)",
        backgroundSize: "contain",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
    };
    const background = (beingHovered || selected) ? hoverStyle : {};
    return (
        <div className="Grid"
             onMouseEnter={() => setBeingHovered(true)}
             onMouseLeave={() => setBeingHovered(false)}
             onClick={() => setSelected(!selected)}
             style={background}
             ref={myRef}
        >
            <span>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```